# Styling text in html code tag

Tags: java, html, css, jsf

I want to style some text witch is wrapped in a html `<code>` tag. But the styling is done in server side class. For e.g.:

```
myValue.replaceAll(" " + textToStyle + " ", " <span style=\"color: orange;\"> " + textToStyle + "</span> ");
```

This lines goes as text which is wrapped in `<code>` tag. The text is displayed in JSF datatable:

```
<h:column>
    <code class="dt_row">
        #{myList.myValue}
    </code>
</h:column>
```

`<code>` tag css class:

```
.dt_row {
    height: 8px;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The problem is when the html is rendered in a browser the code is displayed with all tags. I want that not this `<span style=\"color: orange;\">` will be displayed in page but the text value in orange color.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry I lost you near your last line. Do you want to turn off escaping?

Comment: Yes, I want to turn off escaping. For e.g. in my question where class="dt_row", class attribute is in blue color but not for e.g: <span style="color: blue;">class</span>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
#{myList.myValue}
```

you may try

```
<h:outputText value="#{myList.myValue}" escape="false" />
```

Setting "escape" to false should do the work (otherwise the framework will escape the String...).

Answer (score 2):

More elegant way would be to use the style-attribute of the h:outputText component and referring to a bean for the color e.g.:

```
<h:column>
    <code class="dt_row">
        <h:outputText value="#{myList.myValue}" style="color: #{myList.color};" />
    </code>
</h:column>
```

Comment: In effect this solution is far more elegant. And probably the one that would be adopted in a production environment.

Comment: Yes, I agree, if you want to highlight all value which came from myList.myValue. But in my case the value contains more than one word, but only one and specific needs to be highlighted. So previous solutions is best for me.